# P(A|B') from P(A|B)

Tags: probability, statistics

I know $P(A|B)$. From this, is there a formula to get $P(A|B^c)$ where $B^c$ is "not $B$". It seems like there would be some connection similar to $P(A^c|B)=1-P(A|B)$.

Comment: Additional information is required to relate $Pr(A\mid B)$ and $Pr(A\mid B^c)$, for example knowing $Pr( B)$.

Comment: I know P(A and B)

Comment: that is not enough. You need $P(A)$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute
$$
P(A|B')=\frac{P(A\&B')}{P(B')}=\frac{P(A)-P(A\&B)}{1-P(B)}
$$

Note that you need all three probabilities and it is easy to see that they are "independent" (not in the probabilistic sense, but in the sense that they span a 3-dementional real domain).

Answer (score 0):

If you know $P(AB)$ and $P(A|B)$ (and these are not $0$), then 
$P(B) = P(AB)/P(A|B)$.  However, $P(A|B^c)$ could still be anything from $0$ to $1$.  You need one more piece of information, e.g. $P(A)$.  If you have
$P(A)$, then $$P(A|B^c) = \dfrac{P(A B^c)}{P(B^c)} = \dfrac{P(A) - P(AB)}{1 - P(B)}$$